# Predict xgboost model onto raster stack yields error

Tags: r, xgboost, r-raster, terra

I am using an xgboost model to predict onto a raster stack. I have successfully used the same approach with CART, xgb and Random Forest models:

```
library(raster)

# create a RasterStack or RasterBrick with with a set of predictor layers
logo <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
names(logo)

# known presence and absence points
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85,
              66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31,
              22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)
a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
              99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
              37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)

# extract values for points
xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
v <- data.frame(cbind(pa=xy[,1], extract(logo, xy[,2:3])))

xgb <- xgboost(data = data.matrix(subset(v, select = -c(pa))), label = v$pa, 
               nrounds = 5)

raster::predict(model = xgb, logo)
```

But with `xgboost` I get the following error:

> Error in xgb.DMatrix(newdata, missing = missing) :
> xgb.DMatrix does not support construction from list

Comment: please include a minimal, reproducible, self-contained example. For example, adapt the example from `raster::predict`.

Comment: @RobertHijmans I have updated the question by including a minimal, reproducible, self-contained example. I am also facing the same problem. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `predict.xgb.Booster` does not accept a data.frame for argument `newdata` (see `?predict.xgb.Booster`). That is unexpected (all common `predict.*` methods take a data.frame), but we can work around it. I show how to do that below, using the "terra" package instead of the obsolete "raster" package (but the solution is exactly the same for either package).

The example data

```
library(terra)
library(xgboost)    
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85,
              66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31,
              22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)
a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
              99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
              37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)    
xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
v <- extract(logo, xy[,2:3])
xgb <- xgboost(data = data.matrix(v), label=xy[,1], nrounds = 5)
```

The work-around is to write a prediction function that first coerces the data.frame with "new data" to a matrix. We can use that function with `predict<SpatRaster>`

```
xgbpred <- function(model, data, ...) {
    predict(model, newdata=as.matrix(data), ...)
}

p <- predict(logo, model=xgb, fun=xgbpred)
plot(p)
```

[image]